# Customer account navigation link store specific

Tags: customer-account, store-view, layout-update, ce-1.9.2.2

As the title states, I need to add a link to the customer account navigation menu just for one store view of the website.

I tried doing it in this way, in the customer.xml file, with no luck:

```
<customer_account translate="label">
    <label>Customer My Account (All Pages)</label>
    ...
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="customer/account_navigation" name="customer_account_navigation" before="-" template="customer/account/navigation.phtml">
            <action method="addLink" ...
        </block>
    </reference>
    <STORE_english>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label">
                    <label>returns</label>
                    <path>returns</path>
                    <title>returns</title>
           </action>
        </reference>
    </STORE_english>

</customer_account>
```

Comment: Could you add a class to the link and then use CSS to show/hide for the relevant store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Creating Custom Layout Handles**

So ideally, we need a way to define a layout handle for customer nav link. Something like the following:

```
<CUSTOMER_NAV_LINK_STORE_english>
       <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
           <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>returns</name><path>returns</path><label>Returns</label></action>
       </reference>
</CUSTOMER_NAV_LINK_STORE_english>
```

So, we have to follow the steps below:

**Step : 1** First, we will create `app/etc/modules/AR_Customhandle.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AR_Customhandle>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </AR_Customhandle>
    </modules>
</config>
```

**Step : 2** Now, we will create a `config.xml` file:  `app/code/local/AR/Customhandle/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <AR_Customhandle>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </AR_Customhandle>
    </modules>
     <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customhandle>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>AR_Customhandle</module>
                    <frontName>customhandle</frontName>
                </args>
            </customhandle>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customhandle>
                    <file>customhandle.xml</file>
                </customhandle>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <global>
        <events>
            <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <customer_nav_link_handle>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>customhandle/observer</class>
                        <method>addCustomerNavLinkHandle</method>
                    </customer_nav_link_handle>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

**Step : 3** Now, we will create a class: `AR_Customhandle_Model_Observer` and a method: `addCustomerNavLinkHandle()` in `app/code/local/Magebse/Customhandle/Model/Observer.php`

```
<?php
class AR_Customhandle_Model_Observer
{
    public function addCustomerNavLinkHandle(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $storeCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode();
        $update = $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate();
        $update->addHandle('CUSTOMER_NAV_LINK_STORE_' . $storeCode);
    }
}
```

**Step : 4** Now, we will create a layout file : `app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/layout/customhandle.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
 <CUSTOMER_NAV_LINK_STORE_english>
       <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
           <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="customer"><name>returns</name><path>returns</path><label>Returns</label></action>
       </reference>
 </CUSTOMER_NAV_LINK_STORE_english>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only two options to achieve this

1. Create your own layout handler like Abdul explained in his answer
2. Create a new layout theme for your store view and add the link there.

**Background**

Magento layout handles will be processed in a certain order. If you take a look at the handles on the `customer_account_page` you'll notice that the `STORE_english` [STORE_default] handle gets fired right after all the default handles have ran. Only then Magento processes the `customer_account_index` handle which loads the `customer_account_navigation`.

So your layout update with `<STORE_english>` can't work because the reference blocks do not exist.

Since we can't nest any layout updates we have to go with option #1 or #2